Curtin Command Install Stuck
I'm installing the 24.04 LTS live on my usb 2, and it's been 4 hours stuck in curtin install command

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
